# Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I FOUND MY MISTAKE!!! This is wrong `CASE WHEN regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^/]*$') AS download,`

I just deleted 'Case when' and it works! Thank you everyone! :)

I have this data:

1. `DE-Internet-LTE`
2. `AE-Internet-Ethernet-10M/30M`

How can I get only the value "10M"? and if there's none, I want it to return to null.

I used this query:

`regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^-/]*$') AS upload`

On the second row, it gives the result "10M" but on the first row it return to "LTE" instead of "null".

I'm using SQL Tool 1.8 b38.

UPDATE:
My full query:
`

> SELECT DISTINCT artikel.artnr1, L1.lfnr1 AS lfnr, L1.name1 AS lf_name,
> artikel.abez1, regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?){1}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '',
> 2) AS land, regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){1}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '',
> 2) AS Technologie, CASE WHEN
> regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){2}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) IS NULL
> THEN regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^-]*$') ELSE
> regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){2}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) END AS
> Topologie, regexp_substr(regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,
> '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') AS upload, CASE WHEN
> regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^/]*$') AS download,
> bestanfragepos.preis / bestanfrage.bwkurs, 'Anfrage' AS Art,
> To_Char(bestanfrage.lfdanfrage), bestanfrage.anfragedatum, CASE WHEN
> InStr(angaufgut.reserve1, '.') > 1 THEN Months_Between(
> bestanfrage.anfragedatum, To_Date(angaufgut.reserve1)) ELSE
> To_Number(angaufgut.reserve1) end AS Laufzeit FROM artikel inner join
> modell ON modell.lfdnr = artikel.lfdmodnr left join bestanfragepos ON
> artikel.lfdnr = bestanfragepos.lfdartnr left join bestanfrage ON
> bestanfragepos.lfdanfrage = bestanfrage.lfdanfrage left join lieferant
> L1 ON L1.liefnr = bestanfrage.lfdliefnr left JOIN angaufgut ON
> bestanfragepos.lfdangaufgutnr = angaufgut.lfdnr WHERE Lower(modcode)
> LIKE 'ac%' AND Lower(abez1) NOT LIKE 'cust%' and artikel.mandant = 1
> AND bestanfragepos.preis != 0 ORDER BY abez1 /

`

it gives error ora-00920 invalid relational operator.

It only worked on a single data when I used this:

`SELECT regexp_substr(regexp_substr(artikelbez, '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') FROM nag_reporting_leitungspreise WHERE art = 'Vertrag' AND REF = 3791`

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(artikel.abez1, '.*-([[:alnum:]]+)/[[:alnum:]]+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: I don't know. I can't open my SQL Server Database Engine, I don't have the authority from my company, so can't see what kind of database I have.

Comment: @wiktor it does't work. It gives error ORA-00920 invalid relational operator

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(artikel.abez1, '.*-([[:alnum:]]+)/[[:alnum:]]+$|.+', '\1')`

Comment: @wiktor could you please tell me why do you use regexp_replace here? and what does :alnum here do?

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: it partially works. When I used it to a single data, yes. But when I combine with my inner join, I got the same error.

Comment: @ellawidya please update your question with a full query that returns ora-920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns 30M.  If you really want 10M, then this should do what you want:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(t.abez1, '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') AS upload
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40ed34b0af6cd5ad1d335c3b44bac376) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it did return to 30M, didn't see it clearly.
However, I got the same error, just like the code from @Wiktor.

So when I used this it worked:

'
SELECT regexp_substr(regexp_substr(artikelbez, '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') FROM nag_reporting_leitungspreise
WHERE art = 'Vertrag' AND REF = 3791'

But when I combined it with another inner join, it gives error ORA-00920 invalid relational operator.

Comment: Overall code:"SELECT DISTINCT artikel.artnr1, L1.lfnr1 AS lfnr, L1.name1 AS lf_name, artikel.abez1,
regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?){1}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) AS land,
regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){1}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) AS Technologie,
CASE WHEN regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){2}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) IS NULL THEN regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^-]*$') ELSE regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'(.*?-){2}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2) END AS Topologie,
regexp_substr(regexp_substr(artikel.abez1, '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') AS upload,
CASE WHEN regexp_substr(artikel.abez1,'[^/]*$') AS download,"

Comment: "bestanfragepos.preis / bestanfrage.bwkurs, 'Anfrage' AS Art, To_Char(bestanfrage.lfdanfrage),
bestanfrage.anfragedatum, CASE WHEN InStr(angaufgut.reserve1, '.') > 1 THEN Months_Between( bestanfrage.anfragedatum, To_Date(angaufgut.reserve1)) ELSE To_Number(angaufgut.reserve1) end AS Laufzeit
FROM artikel
inner join modell ON modell.lfdnr = artikel.lfdmodnr
left join bestanfragepos ON artikel.lfdnr = bestanfragepos.lfdartnr
left join bestanfrage ON bestanfragepos.lfdanfrage = bestanfrage.lfdanfrage
left join lieferant L1 ON L1.liefnr = bestanfrage.lfdliefnr"

Comment: "left JOIN angaufgut ON bestanfragepos.lfdangaufgutnr = angaufgut.lfdnr
WHERE Lower(modcode) LIKE 'ac%'
AND Lower(abez1) NOT LIKE 'cust%'
and artikel.mandant = 1 AND bestanfragepos.preis != 0
ORDER BY abez1
/"

Comment: @ellawidya . . . It sounds like you might have a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with t(str) as (
select * from table(ku$_vcnt(
'DE-Internet-LTE',
'AE-Internet-Ethernet-10M/30M',
'AE-Internet-Ethernet-20m/40m',
'AE-Internet-Ethernet-300M/500M',
'AE-Internet-Ethernet-4000k/600k',
'AE-Internet-Ethernet-200M'
))
)
select 
  str, 
  regexp_substr(str, '(\d+(k|m))(/\d+(k|m))?',1,1,'i',1) upload,
  regexp_substr(str, '/(\d+(k|m))',1,1,'i',1) download
from t;
```

Results:

```
STR                                 UPLOAD  DOWNLOAD
----------------------------------- ------- --------
DE-Internet-LTE
AE-Internet-Ethernet-10M/30M        10M     30M
AE-Internet-Ethernet-20m/40m        20m     40m
AE-Internet-Ethernet-300M/500M      300M    500M
AE-Internet-Ethernet-4000k/600k     4000k   600k
AE-Internet-Ethernet-200M           200M
```

Comment: you're also using (\d+) on your query. What does "d" on this query do? Could you please kindly explain? Because when I removed the "d", it gives "null" result. Thank you.

Comment: That means just any digit

Comment: `\d+` means 1+ digits

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the below solution:

```
with t(str) as 
(
    select  column_value 
    from    table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
            'DE-Internet-LTE',
            'AE-Internet-Ethernet-10M/30M',
            'AE-Internet-Ethernet-20m/40m',
            'AE-Internet-Ethernet-300M/500M',
            'AE-Internet-Ethernet-4000k/600k',
            'AE-Internet-Ethernet-200M'
            ))
)
select  str, 
        regexp_substr(str, '-(\d+.*?)(/|$)',1,1,null,1) as upload,
        regexp_substr(str, '/(\d+.*?)$',1,1,null,1) as download,
        regexp_substr(regexp_substr(str, '([^-/]+)/[^-/]+$'), '^[^-/]+') as Gordan_Linoff_upload
from    t;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this part: (\d+)
What does "d" on this query do? Could you please kindly explain? Thank you.

Comment: \d represents a single digit. So, \d+ says one or more digits. Since you are expecting a number (ie multiple digits) I have used \d+

Comment: Glad I could help. Kindly mark my answer as useful if it did really help you.